# Scala.js support for scala.xml and scala.compiler

Tags: scala, scala.js

Can [scala.xml](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml) (XML literals in particular) or `scala-compiler` be used in Scala.js projects?

This seems like a very basic question, however I did not find this documented anywhere, esp. not in [Semantics of Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/semantics.html), where lack of support for `scala-reflection` is discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scala.compiler` (or, to be precise, `scala.tools.nsc`) is definitely not supported. An easy way to figure that out is that trying out the following `libraryDependencies` would fail to resolve:

```
"org.scala-lang" %%% "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

because there is no Scala.js artifact published for `scala-compiler.jar`.

**Edit:** `scala-xml` has been available for Scala.js since version 1.1.0, as you can see [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cscala-xml).

So, it is "documented" in the sense that artifacts are published or not for these libraries with Scala.js.

Usually, libraries who do provide support for Scala.js advertise it on their README. If they do not, the ultimate source of truth is whether artifacts are published or not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is "no" for both of these. (sjrd will correct me if I'm wrong.) Basically, any library that is JVM dependent doesn't work on Scala.js.

Comment: I suppose so - but is this documented somewhere, or just understood to be obvious? Compared to other libraries, those are often considered more or less a part of the language, same as `scala.reflection`.